# Print greatest number for types in c - struggling with formatting correct types

Tags: c, printf, overflow

I have an exercise that goes like:

> Write a program to discover the greatest number representable by the short,
> int, long int, and long long int data types.

I solved it in 3 ways and I'd like to use the most elegant to me, using shift operator.
But I cannot find a way to print the output correctly, for when I use `printf` to format a number, it modifies the result I found and goes in overflow.

Could you tell how to print correctly final results ?
Why does casting a smaller type into a bigger one, changes the number ?

I don't understand why the only one that turns correct is the one for `short` type. `Int`, `long int` and `long long int` go on overflow, in spite format declaration seems correct to me.

```
printf("Greatest short: %d \n", (1 << sizeof(short) * 8) - 1);
printf("Greatest int: %i \n", (1 << sizeof(int) * 8) - 1 ); //overflow
printf("Greatest long int: %li \n",  (long int) (1 << sizeof(long int) * 8) - 1 ); // overflow
printf("Greatest long int: %lli \n",  (long long int) (1 << sizeof(long long int) * 8) - 1 ); //overflow
```

Comment: You're overflowing the maximum value of the signed values.

Answer (score 0):

For the two's complement max positive number you need to:

```
printf("Greatest short: %d \n", (1 << (sizeof(short)) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
printf("Greatest int: %i \n", (1U << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1);
printf("Greatest long int: %li \n",  (long int) ((1UL << (sizeof(long int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1));
printf("Greatest long long int: %lli \n",  (long long int) ((1ULL << (sizeof(long long int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1) );
```

Comment: Could you clarify ?
I learnt that `Char_bit` for posix systems is `== 8`, and in general we can assume architectures use char type in 8 bits.
Why the unsigned number has to be `2 ^ (number_of_bytes * number_bits - 1) -1` and not  `2 ^ (number_of_bytes * number_bits) -1`  ? Why extra `-1`?

Comment: I also don't understand well the difference of `1`, `1U`, etc. When doing the shift operator, I understand I will move the 1 bit on the left for `number_of_bytes*char_bit` positions. E.g. Can I say that, for a 4 bit number, the operation of `1 << 4` is equivalent to filling `1111` , plus `-1` as it will be the last number before overflow (that last left 1 will spill over)? So why do I need to specify that that 1 digit is `1U` or `1UL` ?  Can you expand how the bitwise operation works in `(1 << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1)` VS `(1U << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1)`(note using `1U`)?